# Jeju visa procedures for Nigeria and Ghana

Tags: air-travel, south-korea, nigerian-citizens, ghanaian-citizens, jeju

How do I apply visa to Jeju Island with Nigerian and Ghanese passports?

Answer (score 3):

For Jeju island, Nigerian and Ghana passport holders need a visa for South Korea.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea#Jeju_Island

For the tourism purposes, you are required to apply for B-2-2 for Jeju island in your nearest embassy.

Nigeria: http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/ng-en/index.do
Ghana: http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/gh-en/index.do